# Looking for a script to overlay a fullscreen slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox, slideshow, fullscreen

I am looking for a script for overlaying a full screen image slideshow over the top of a webpage. I am familiar with scripts that generate a fullscreen background, and also lightbox scripts, but am looking for a fullscreen slideshow that fills the entire browser window with a letterbox to keep the images in the correct proportions, ideally with transition effects.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks,

Nick

Comment: that actually sounds like a lightbox, weirdly enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go for [FancyBox](http://fancybox.net/)

Change the width and height to 100% for covering entire browser.

Comment: thanks.  i like the minimal look of fancybox, and with margin and padding set to 0 and autoscale set to true, it extends to the edge of the browser window, but never overflows. I have it working with a gallery of images, but haven't worked out how to get the images to play automatically as a slideshow.  This doesn't appear to be built in to fancybox, so may require some other code.  Do you know how to implement this?

Comment: yes, i'd like to keep the slideshow running.  ideally I would also have a pause/play button, that would only show on hovering over the image (like the previous/next buttons) and which would pause and restart the slideshow.  but having a slideshow is the main thing!

Comment: ok. then go for this:
http://www.twospy.com/galleriffic/
and accept the answer if its right. and upvote it too.

Comment: thanks, but it looks like galleriffic isn't an overlay/lightbox.  were you suggesting that I use galleriffic with fancybox, perhaps as inline html or an iframe?

Comment: I have worked out that by adding `setInterval($.fancybox.next, 7000);` to my fancybox script I can get a slideshow playing, and I have asked a question on the fancybox google group about adding a play/pause button.  I have marked the question as answered, and I am sure that the gallerific solution would work, but may not provide exactly what I am looking for (a play/pause button overlayed over the slideshow when the user hovers over it), and if possible I would rather not use another script.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

This is a great jQuery HTML5 fullscreen slideshow. Very basic and minimal.

http://eikes.github.com/jquery.fullscreen.js/

Answer (score 1):

I like [Vegas Background jQuery plugin](http://web-resources.net/gallery/fullscreen-background-slideshow-overlay-support.html). An overlay with a texture can be added to mask the image degradation effects.

http://web-resources.net/gallery/fullscreen-background-slideshow-overlay-support.html

Answer (score 0):

You can also check this one: [FullScreen Background Slider](http://sympies.com/fullscreen_background_slider/)

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Could you provide a summary of what's in that link?

Comment: Hello! It is a Fullscreen Image Slider powered by CSS3 transitions, Text on Image Support and other customization options.