# Stretching a small image to the window

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, fancybox, stretch

How do I fully stretch an image to a window via Fancybox? (Fancybox 2) 
The fancybox stretches as big as the image size, but no further.

I noticed a number of CSS limits stuck in the fancybox css, like:

```
.fancybox-image, .fancybox-iframe {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.fancybox-image {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

Taking the `max-width/height` out and setting let's say `width/height` to `200%` does stretch the image, but the containing rectangle itself (ie: the fancybox) is the same size, and it is no longer centered.

I am using the inline method with eg: `jQuery(".fancybox").fancybox()`

Comment: http://fancybox.net/api there is variables like width/height for fancybox size

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of [Looking for a script to overlay a fullscreen slideshow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769828/looking-for-a-script-to-overlay-a-fullscreen-slideshow/5770458#5770458)

Comment: you could also check http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#useful, No.16 ... or this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/14221031/1055987

Comment: The "supersized effect" example is close, but it needs to be stretched to the size of the browser window, preserve the aspect ratio, and keep the buttons on the border instead of in the image. Basically can do everything now except preserving the aspect ratio. Kind of important, that.

Comment: And now, something similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14617125/fancybox-2-control-stretching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The i-pretty-much-gives-up-except-for-some-cool-but-useless-stuff approach:

```
.fancybox({
 afterLoad  : function () {
  function gcd (x, y) {while (y != 0) {var z = x % y; x = y; y = z;} return x}
  var body = $(document.body)
  if (this.width/this.height > 1) {
   // Max size is document body width.
   var body_width = body.width()
   var current_multiplier = gcd (this.width, body_width)
   if (current_multiplier == 1) current_multiplier = body_width
  } else {
   // Max size is document body height.
   var body_height = body.height()
   var current_multiplier = gcd (this.height, body_height)
   if (current_multiplier == 1) current_multiplier = body_height
  }
  this.width  = this.width  * current_multiplier
  this.height = this.height * current_multiplier
 }
})
```